# CSS Media queries behaving differently on different browsers

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've recently uploaded my website to a domain, however after everything works perfectly locally, I am getting different results when loading the site with an iphone. I am getting different results on different browsers.

Here is the media query I am using, targeted at iphone users. On safari, header text display's black even though I'd like it to be white. On chrome and opera this is not an issue. However, the background image is actually displaying on safari, whereas it is not on chrome or opera.

Website is benmirageas.com

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 627px){
    #header{
        background-image: url(Images/iphone_background.jpg);
        color: #080808;
    }
    .header-text{
        margin-top: 10%;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .header-text h1{
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    nav .fa-solid{
        display: block;
        font-size: 25px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 15px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    nav ul{
        background: #ff004f;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -200px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100vh;
        padding-top: 50px;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: right 0.5s;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin: 25px;
    }
    nav ul .fa-solid{
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .sub-title{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .about-col-1, .about-col-2{
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    .about-col-1{
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .about-col-2{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .tab-links{
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .contact-left, .contact-right{
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    #msg{
        color: #61b752;
        margin-top: -20px;
        display: block;
        }
    .layer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6), #ff004f);
        border-radius: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        
    }
    
}
```

I am a beginner, I've googled everything under the sun to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand pixel density and how it relates to media queries? The iPhone's resolution may be doubled or tripled, so you'd need to account for that.

Comment: Are you using the `<meta>` for viewport? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: What is the significance of `627px`? You do know [there's more than 1 model of iPhone](https://www.knowyourmobile.com/user-guides/iphone-size-comparison-chart/), with dozens of screen-sizes and [pixel-dimensions](https://www.ios-resolution.com/), right?

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML and look at how to make a runnable snippet which will allow us to experience the problem. As  IOS browsers are based on the same engine it is indeed strange that you are getting different results. Please also tell us the model of iPhone you are testing on (is it a real device or on an emulator?).

Comment: One of your problems is that in the background image the person is not centered so on narrow devices when you position the background image as center either none, or only part, of the person shows (I saw this on an emulated iPhoneSE). You need to use an image with the person dead center.